# Sarkovskii ordering is not a well-ordering?

Tags: dynamical-systems

The Wikipedia article on [Sarkovskii's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharkovskii's_theorem) claims that the Sarkovskii ordering of the natural numbers is not a well-ordering, stating:

> Note that this ordering is not a well-ordering, since the set
>   $$\left\{ 2^k \mid k \in \mathbb{N} \right\}$$
>   doesn't have a least element.

I cannot see how this is true. Surely the element $2^0$ is a least element of this set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$2^0$ is least in the usual ordering on the natural numbers, but not in the Sarkovskii ordering, which is a *different* ordering of the naturals.  In this ordering, $2^0=1$ is actually the largest natural number, and the smallest is $3$.

$$3<5<\cdots<2^4<2^3<2^2<2^1<2^0$$

Comment: Oh, of course! That was stupid of me. I've always seen the Sarkovskii ordering defined in the opposite way, i.e. $3$ is the largest number and $1$ is the smallest. I didn't read the article carefully enough. Now it makes sense, thank you.